# Simply Connected sets

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, connectedness

In my textbook it states, that the Union of two open docs is simply connected but not connected

Why is this. I know simply connected means any closed path or loop can be shrunk to a point continuously. Why is this simply connected but image 3 in the link below is not.
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SimplyConnected.html

Can you explain this informally please

Comment: What is an open doc?

Comment: I've always seen definitions of simple connectedness requiring the space to be path connected.

Answer (score 0):

In the Wolfram Alpha definition, it is required that the domain be path-connected to begin with. I guess it depends on which definition you're using; if only your condition (on loop shrinking) were imposed, then $3$ would be simply connected.